# kubernetes: could not find PersistentVolume hostpath on windows

Tags: docker, kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

kubernetes: could not find PersistentVolume hostpath on windows 11.

> kubectl describe pv/pvc-4a7bc0ff-9195-4f2f-bd70-9dfd1f8cd065

```
Name:            pvc-4a7bc0ff-9195-4f2f-bd70-9dfd1f8cd065
Labels:          <none>
Annotations:     docker.io/hostpath: /var/lib/k8s-pvs/my-pv-claim/pvc-4a7bc0ff-9195-4f2f-bd70-9dfd1f8cd065
                 pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: docker.io/hostpath
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    hostpath
Status:          Bound
Claim:           default/my-pv-claim
Reclaim Policy:  Delete
Access Modes:    RWO
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        20Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:
Source:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/lib/k8s-pvs/my-pv-claim/pvc-4a7bc0ff-9195-4f2f-bd70-9dfd1f8cd065
    HostPathType:
Events:            <none>
```

But could not find the path /var/lib/k8s-pvs/my-pv-claim/pvc-4a7bc0ff-9195-4f2f-bd70-9dfd1f8cd065 on windows 11 WSL.